How do I access member variables from gpio callback
Using the Raspberry Pi Pico SDK, I see that the repeating_timer callback functions have option input for user data. However, the gpio_set_irq_callback  function has no user data parameter.
Is there a way to access the member variables from gpio callback?
Should I go about implementing a user data parameter by changing my local sdk? How would I go about this?
void callback(uint gpio, uint32_t event_mask){
    if(gpio_get(pina)){
        //I want to call lcdmenu.up()
    }
    else{
        //lcdmenu.down()
    }
}


class lcdmenu
{
protected:
    command **items;
    int menutop = 0;
    int numitems;
    int menuselect = 0;   

public:
    lcdmenu(command **list, int length);
    void render();
    void down();
    void up();
    void enter();

};

lcdmenu::lcdmenu(command **list, int length)
{

    gpio_set_irq_enabled_with_callback(pinb, GPIO_IRQ_EDGE_FALL, true, &callback);
    numitems = length;
    items = list;
    render();
}



You don't need interrupts to implement a menu on an LCD, and also using them makes it harder to implement debouncing for the button inputs.  You can just do all this from the main loop.
